# How to add key to $addToSet in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a key inside mongodb add function. I am doing this right now.

```
$addToSet : {
    "msges":{
            time:{"from":uname,"title":title,"msg":msg,"read":false}
        }
    }
```

time is a variable that is coming from the paramater. It has time inside it as hh:mm:ss A. But when the query runs, instead of time as key, string "time" gets print as key. Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your variable in `[]` :

```
$addToSet: {
    "msges": {
        [time]: { "from": uname, "title": title, "msg": msg, "read": false }
    }
}
```

For instance :

```
var myfield = "custom_field";

db.test.update({
    _id: 1
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        letters: [{
            [myfield]: 1
        }, {
            [myfield]: 2
        }]
    }
})
```

It gives :

```
{ "_id" : 1, "letters" : [ [ { "custom_field" : 1 }, { "custom_field" : 2 } ] ] }
```

Comment: when i change it to [time] it says unexpected token ]